# Rigging a Character Model- Bone Heat Weighting Error

Tags: rigging

Here is the blend file:  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35832.  I am getting the "bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" error when I click "Armature Deform: With Automatic Weights."

I see from google this is a very common issue, but all of the solutions I've found are different from one another or sound model-specific.  I've tried many of the methods I've seen suggested (removing doubles, recalculating normals, and adding a subsurface modifier), but so far those don't seem to work (and the other solutions suggested start to sound complex).

I followed a tutorial online for the rigging-- this one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cGvalWG8HBU. I made the model in zbrush.  One of the answers suggested to not even try if the model is in any way asymmetric-- I'm not sure if this model 100% is (though when I look at it, it seems symmetric) -- but that answer was from 2008 or so, and I don't know if it's been fixed in later versions of Blender.  (And if there are good tutorials about rigging asymmetric models, I haven't seen those).

Thank you for any help.